# How do I add multi-threading to display graphics to avoid thread overload?

Tags: android, multithreading, graphics

I have written a little program which works fine using a single thread but I would like to call the graphic via a separate thread.

The call for the graphic is from a button press. (this works fine)

```
            case R.id.button3:
            draw = new Draw(this);
            setContentView(draw);
            break;
```

If I try to encase this code like this...

```
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    draw = new Draw(this);
                    setContentView(draw);
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

I get a problem with (this). I don't understand completely what "this" is doing except that it refers to the class it is within.
Is the answer simple?
I am trying to do this because I have the following message "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Modifying UI from non-ui thread is prohibited in Android in most cases. Only SurfaceView can be drawed async.

And this return and instance of `Runnable` in your case. Try .this

Comment: If I do this I get the following error on "setContentView(draw);" "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Comment: Check my answer plz

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the context from the activity.

**this** refers to the class you are in. You are calling **this** in a Thread class, so **this** is associated with the Thread.

Comment: You are probably correct. Within the Draw class there is the following line: "public Draw(Context context)". Changing  to "draw = new draw Draw(Context context)" just gives me another error.

Comment: If you are in a Activity, try this: "draw = new Draw(YourActivityName.this)"

Comment: If I do this I get the following error on "setContentView(draw);" "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your anonymous class is enclosed in a class name `Outer`, then you can write:

```
class Outer {
    ...
    ... someMethod(...) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                draw = new Draw(Outer.this); // access enclosing instance
                setContentView(draw);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    ...
}
```

Beware that you shouldn't draw asynchronously...

Comment: If I do this I get the following error on "setContentView(draw);"
"android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Comment: Sorry if I am being stupid but I really don't understand this.